# Windows 10 Universal App Google Calendar API

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, win-universal-app, uwp

I am working on a project and am trying to hit the google calendar API v3 and followed all of the steps outlined by Google for previous .NET clients to no avail.

I tried this, but nothing for universal apps and things here aren't available.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet

I also tried this with no luck either (all of the brutal steps):
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth

I would HATE for the answer to be things like "sync to o365 and pull from there", or "stand up a proxy".

Has anybody been able to make this work?

Can anyone get calendar information from google calendars and display it in a windows universal app?

Thank you for any help or meaningful insight.

PS: Snippet of code that I thought may work...but isn't.

```
    var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/client_secrets.json"),
    new[] { Uri.EscapeUriString(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar) },
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None);
var calendarService = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Windows 8.1 Calendar sample"
    });
var calendarListResource = await calendarService.CalendarList.List().ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: Is the Windows Universal App similar to C#.NET? (Haven't used C# for a long time). What kind of errors are you experiencing? Logs would definitely help the community understand the case.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by reconfiguring my app in the google api dev console.

Comment: What did you change? What was it at?